# Liking a comment in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have been learning rails and building blogs site and introduced the like model for posts.
I have created a like model for liking a blog post using polymorphic association with user `user_id` and blogs `blog_id`.
and i want to have a like button for a comments on each blog post, and i don't know which way to do is better

1. can i have a `comment_id` on the same like model  , will it be correct or may break polymorphic association 
   or
2. Should i make a totally different like model for comments with `user_id` and `comment_id` as a foreign key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **Polymorphic Association** here. But I notice that you have the wrong understanding of Polymorphic Association in the above explanation because you are referencing `Blog` & `Comment` via `blog_id` & `comment_id` respectively in the `Like` model instead of referencing those through `likeable`(i.e., `likeable_id` & `likeable_type`). Follow the below steps for better understanding.

- Generate `Like` model

```
rails g model Like user:references likeable:references{polymorphic}
```

- `Like` model migration should look like this

```
class CreateLikes < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :likes do |t|
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :likeable, polymorphic: true, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

- Like model

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :likeable, polymorphic: true
end
```

- Blog model

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :likes, as: :likeable
end
```

- Comment model

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :likes, as: :likeable
end
```

- Table entries of `Like` model should look similar to this

```
 => #<Like:0x00# id: 1, user_id: 1, likeable_id: 1, likeable_type: "Blog", created_at: <timestamp>, updated_at: <timestamp>>

 => #<Like:0x00# id: 2, user_id: 1, likeable_id: 2, likeable_type: "Comment", created_at: <timestamp>, updated_at: <timestamp>>
```